# Trying to put 3 columns on my footer but no result

Tags: html, css

I try to make a footer with 3 cols but I can't make it. So here is the result I try to do

[image]

But instead of this I get this result

[image]

Here is my html and CSS code:

```
.footer {
background:none #333;
height:100%;
margin:0 10px;
padding:0;
}

.footer div:first-child {
float:left;
margin:0 0 0 20px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.footer div:first-child ul {
list-style:none;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
padding:10px 0 0;
}
 .footer div:first-child ul li {
color:#026593;
float:left;
font-size:11px;
}
.footer div:first-child ul li:first-child a {
padding-left:0;
}
.footer div:first-child ul li a {
color:#026593;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
line-height:30px;
padding:0 13px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.footer div:first-child ul li a:hover, .footer div:first-child ul li.selected a {
color:#ff7500;
   }
 .footer div:first-child p {
color:#026593;
display:block;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
line-height:11px;
margin:-2px 0 0;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.footer div.connect {
float:right;
padding:20px 20px 0;
}
.footer div.connect span {
color:#ff7500;
float:left;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
line-height:12px;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
 .footer div.connect a {
float:left;
height:22px;
margin:0 0 0 7px;
text-indent:-99999px;
width:23px;
 }
.footer aside h4{
color: #1b9bff;
padding-left: 6.3789%;
padding-top: 2%;
margin-bottom: -1%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
width: 18.23%;
 }
.footer div h4{
color: #1b9bff;
padding-left: 6.3789%;
padding-top: 2%;
margin-bottom: -1%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
width: 18.23%;
float: left;
}
.footer aside ul li{
color :#1b9bff;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
width: 20%;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: small;
float: left;
 }
.footer aside ul li a:hover{
color: #1b9bff;
}
.footer p{
color: #1b9bff;
padding-left: 28%;
 }
.footer div p{
color :#1b9bff;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
width: 20%;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: small;
float: left;
 }
 .footer div img{
padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
.footer div ul li a:hover{
color: #1b9bff;
 }
```

And my html code

```
         <div id="main-footer">
       <div class="footer">
                    <aside>

                        <h4>Sitemap</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </aside>
                        <div>
                            <h4>Menu</h4>
                        <img src="./images/gpwa.gif" />
                        <img src="./images/18.png" />
                        <img src="./images/21.png" />
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h4>Terms</h4>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.footer {
    background: none #333;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.footer div:first-child {
float:left;
margin:0 0 0 20px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.footer div:first-child ul {
list-style:none;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
padding:10px 0 0;
}
 .footer div:first-child ul li {
color:#026593;
float:left;
font-size:11px;
}
.footer div:first-child ul li:first-child a {
padding-left:0;
}
.footer div:first-child ul li a {
color:#026593;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
line-height:30px;
padding:0 13px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.footer div:first-child ul li a:hover, .footer div:first-child ul li.selected a {
color:#ff7500;
   }
 .footer div:first-child p {
color:#026593;
display:block;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
line-height:11px;
margin:-2px 0 0;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.footer div.connect {
float:right;
padding:20px 20px 0;
}
.footer div.connect span {
color:#ff7500;
float:left;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
line-height:12px;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

.flex-column {
  display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
 .footer div.connect a {
float:left;
height:22px;
margin:0 0 0 7px;
text-indent:-99999px;
width:23px;
 }
.footer aside h4{
color: #1b9bff;
padding-left: 6.3789%;
margin-bottom: -1%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
width: 18.23%;
 }
.footer div h4{
color: #1b9bff;
padding-left: 6.3789%;
padding-top: 2%;
margin-bottom: -1%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
width: 18.23%;
float: left;
}
.footer aside ul li{
color :#1b9bff;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
width: 20%;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: small;
float: left;
 }
.footer aside ul li a:hover{
color: #1b9bff;
}
.footer p{
color: #1b9bff;
padding-left: 28%;
 }
.footer div p{
color :#1b9bff;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
width: 20%;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: small;
float: left;
 }
 .footer div img{
padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
.footer div ul li a:hover{
color: #1b9bff;
 }
```

```html
  <div id="main-footer">
       <div class="footer">
                    <aside>

                        <h4>Sitemap</h4>
                        <ul class="flex-column">
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </aside>
                        <div class="flex-column">
                            <h4>Menu</h4>
                        <img src="./images/gpwa.gif" />
                        <img src="./images/18.png" />
                        <img src="./images/21.png" />
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex-column">
                            <h4>Terms</h4>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

I inserted some `flexbox` elements to the divs and the whole footer. As mentioned, this code needs some cleaning. I'm just giving the skeleton so you can change it after.

Answer (score 2):

this code will help resolve the problem

```
<style>
        .footer {
            display: flex;
        }
        aside , div {
            flex: 1;
        }
        .terms p{
            display: inline-block;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="main-footer">
       <div class="footer">
                    <aside>

                        <h4>Sitemap</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </aside>
                        <div>
                            <h4>Menu</h4>
                        <img src="./images/gpwa.gif" />
                        <img src="./images/18.png" />
                        <img src="./images/21.png" />
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="terms">
                            <h4>Terms</h4>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

If some issues then lemme know

Answer (score 2):

This will surely Help you

CSS

```
  .col { 
      background: #0a5173;
      float: left;
      padding: 30px 0 0 35px;
      width: 310px;
    }

    .col:first-child {
      padding: 30px 0 0 0;
    }

    h2 { 
      background: url(extra-title-bg.jpg); 
      color: #FFF;
      float: left; 
      font: bold 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
      font-variant: small-caps; 
      margin: 0 0 20px 0; 
      padding: 9px 0 0 19px; 
      height: 33px; 
      width: 291px;
    }

    ul { 
      list-style: none; 
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0; 
    }

    li { 
      background: url(extra-links-bg.jpg); 
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #25c3ba; 
      border-top: 1px dotted #25c3ba; 
      float: left; 
      height: 35px; 
      margin: 3px 0;
      padding: 0; 
      width: 310px; 
    }

    li a { 
      color: #FFF;
      display: block;
      float: left; 
      font: normal 12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
      padding: 10px 0 0 19px; 
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    li:hover { 
      background: #5fa4c5;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="col">
  <h2>recent entries</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <h2>recent comments</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <h2>featured on</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh man that's some incredibly ugly code.
You should really clean this up. Anyway display your footer as flex and add some classes to your 3 container divs. I added col-3, and I've set it's width to 33.33%.

```css
.footer {
 display: flex;
 background: #212121;
 color: white;
 padding: 20px;
 box-sizing : border-box;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.menu__items ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-footer">
       <div class="footer">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <h4>Sitemap</h4>
                        <div class="menu__items">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <h4>Menu</h4>
                        <img src="./images/gpwa.gif" />
                        <img src="./images/18.png" />
                        <img src="./images/21.png" />
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        <p>I put some text here</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <h4>Terms</h4>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                            <p>I put some text here</p>
                        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]Add this styling to your css file. And rearrange as per your css it will work.

```
.footer {
  float left;
}
aside, div, div {
 float: left; width: 33%;
}
.footer aside h4 { width: 90%;}
aside ul {margin:0; padding:0;}
.footer aside ul li {width: 100%;}
.footer div h4 {width: 90%;}
.footer div p {width: 100%}
.footer p {padding: 10%}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the unnecessary floats from:

```
.footer div:first-child ul li
.footer div.connect a
.footer div h4
.footer aside ul li
.footer div p
```

And add float: left property to div and aside:

```
div, aside {
  float: left;
}
```

And as an advice, clean up your css. Many of those properties seem kind of unnecessary..

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```css
.col-footer{width:30%; float:left;display:block; margin:1.5%;}

.col-footer li{width:100%}

.col-footer p{width:100%}

.footer {
background:none #333;
height:100%;
margin:0 10px;
padding:0;
}

.footer div:first-child {
float:left;
margin:0 0 0 20px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.footer div:first-child ul {
list-style:none;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
padding:10px 0 0;
}
 .footer div:first-child ul li {
color:#026593;
float:left;
font-size:11px;
}

.footer div:first-child ul li a {
color:#026593;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
line-height:30px;
padding:0 13px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.footer div:first-child ul li a:hover, .footer div:first-child ul li.selected a {
color:#ff7500;
   }
 .footer div:first-child p {
color:#026593;
display:block;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
line-height:11px;
margin:-2px 0 0;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.footer div.connect {
float:right;
padding:20px 20px 0;
}
.footer div.connect span {
color:#ff7500;
float:left;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
line-height:12px;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
 .footer div.connect a {
float:left;
height:22px;
margin:0 0 0 7px;
text-indent:-99999px;
width:23px;
 }
.footer aside h4{
color: #1b9bff;
padding-top: 2%;
margin-bottom: -1%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
 }
.footer div h4{
color: #1b9bff;
padding-top: 2%;
margin-bottom: -1%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
.footer aside ul li{
color :#1b9bff;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
width: 100%;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: small;
float: left;
 }
.footer aside ul li a:hover{
color: #1b9bff;
}
.footer p{
color: #1b9bff;
 }
.footer div p{
color :#1b9bff;
padding-top: 5px;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: small;
float: left;
 }
 .footer div img{
padding: 20px 20px 0 0px;
float:left;
display:block;
}
.footer div ul li a:hover{
color: #1b9bff;
 }
```

```html
  <div id="main-footer">
    <div class="footer">  ​
                          
        <div class="col-footer">
            <h4>Sitemap</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
                      
        <div class="col-footer">
            <h4>Menu</h4>
            <img src="./images/gpwa.gif" />
            <img src="./images/18.png" />
            <img src="./images/21.png" />
            <p>I put some text here</p>
            <p>I put some text here</p>
            <p>I put some text here</p>
            <p>I put some text here</p>
            <p>I put some text here</p>
            <p>I put some text here</p>
            <p>I put some text here</p>
        </div>                        
                        
        <div class="col-footer">
            <h4>Terms</h4>
            <p>I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here, I put some text here.</p>
        </div>
​    </div>
</div>
```